# Excel - in A1 enter a numeric value- which refers to Column C + numeric values' value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm asking help on a Excel problem I'm trying to figure out please:

Suppose `C54` has a value of 123 and `C55` has 321

If i make `A1` = 54 Then `B1` (target cell)  becomes the value in cell `C54` ("C" & val(`A1`) = `C54`  =123

If    `A1` = 55 Then `B1` becomes the value in `C55` = 321

Thus, the numeric value entered in A1, refers to that (Numeric value) row in Column C:

Is this possible via a formula please, or via VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the INDIRECT function to get what you're after.  Something like:

```
=INDIRECT("C" & A1)
```

in B1 should get you close.  Keep in mind, INDIRECT is an expensive formula, so if you have a bunch in your workbook, you can expect some performance degradation.